# HAXM is not supported by my PC, any alternatives?

Tags: android-virtual-device, haxm

I installed Android Studio and I had no problems with that. But when I tried to
run the AVD, it got me an error, that told me that my GPU emulation is
disabled.

I searched something about emulators and I found HAXM, that should solve my
problem. But Intel HAXM isnt really working with my AMD computer setup.

Is there any alternative software for HAXM or even for Android studio ? I just need to somehow debug my mobile game.